# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting content from a file and returning it. Like below:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Put some preprocessing here.
    console.log("URL: == ",req.url)

    if(req.url === '/Hello.js'){
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname + '../../../dist/Hello.js'), 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err == ",err)
                onError(err);
                return;
            }
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
            res.type('.js');
            res.send(content)
        });
    }

    next();
});
```

In future I might change the content and send as response.

I tried adding `return` after res.send(content). Still it giving the below error.

```
_http_outgoing.js:530
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: My bet is that the code flow is also executing another one `res.send`, `res.json`, ... so you are getting that error. Debug the call flow to see if there is another middleware in the flow that executes any of those functions before the middleware you are setting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put the `next()` call into an `else` statement to prevent the `res.send` being called later somewhere else in your code.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Put some preprocessing here.
    console.log("URL: == ",req.url)

    if(req.url === '/Hello.js'){
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname + '../../../dist/Hello.js'), 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("err == ",err)
                onError(err);
                return;
            }
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
            res.type('.js');
            res.send(content)
        });
    } else {

        // only call next if the above code was not processed
        next();

    }
});
```

Comment: URL: ==  /
`Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Comment: @Hdhsh you must be calling `res.send` or `res.json` or maybe some other methods multiple times. Probably in some other middleware or route handler.